# can't save new category in magento2 admin panel

Tags: magento2, category, error, adminhtml, category-products

Magento2 admin panel adds new category save then error show.

> "Something went wrong while saving the category."

[image]

So give me a solution.

Comment: Have you checked the magento and server error logs?

Comment: First you check on var exception. PHP file there are some error show, if any other extension installed then please disable and then check.